# Wifi socket connection nullpointer exception at answer

Tags: android, sockets, nullpointerexception, inputstream

I wrote an app which connects to java server. It sends a small message to server and the server answers if the message is "on". For any other case the server is not sending data back.

I wrote a line to check if the inputstream is null or not, but it gets a nullpointer exception on no answer from server. And its wierd for me:

> if (!(line = in.readLine()).equals(null)) {   Remote.setValue(line);
>       }

So if "line" is null, then it should skip (or go to else part if it would where) the part where I set the value, but it hangs on. Simply blocking the whole app.

What I did wrong? Why is this? How can I solve it? Please help!

Comment: That would throw a NullPointerException.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not checking if the input stream is null. You're checking if `readLine` returns null.

Try this instead :

```
if (in != null) {
  line = in.readLine();
  if (line != null) {
      Remote.setValue(line);
  }
}
```

EDIT :

Use `socket.setSoTimeout (x)` where x is some positive integer in order for `in.readLine()` not to block until an input is available.

Comment: in is not null, but the second If is never executed

Comment: You should set a timeout to your socket. Otherwise it would just block until there's something to read.

Comment: Okey, its somehow working... i'm not sure why, but thanks for your help!